# How to use Data Caching in ASP .NET MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I want to share a Queue data structure between all the users of my web application, without using any database. I want this data to be always available and thread safe between all the users. Is caching a good idea? I tried using System.Web.Caching by calling:

```
Queue<int> users= new Queue<int>();

Context.Cache.Insert("users", users, null,  Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

in my Global.axax file, but when I call the cache in my .cs files:

```
( (Queue<int>) Cache["users"] ).Enqueue( newUser);
```

I get the following error:

```
'System.Web.Caching.Cache' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

Am I using caching correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Controller class doesn't have a Cache property like the ASP.NET web forms Page class.  You need to reference it off the HttpContext property.

```
((Queue<int>)HttpContext.Cache["users"]).Enqueue( newUser );
```